# Power Sets in Python

Tags: python, set

My code doesn't work for making power sets in python. It's very close but not right, and I don't know how to improve it. A power set is when you take a set and then you return a tuple of all possible results. I want the set() part at the beginning, also for the result to be SETS not the other things. For example:

```
A power set of {1,2,3} would be:
[set(), {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Here's my code and it almost does it, but doesn't quite.

```
def power_set(lst):
  result = [[]]
  for x in lst:
    result.extend([subset + [x] for subset in result])
  return result
```

Here's some test cases of what it should do and what it does

```
#What it does
power_set({1,2,3}
>>>[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
#What it should do (like stated above)
power_set({1,2,3})
>>>[set(), {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

This is NOT HOMEWORK, I am doing this as a project to understand sets better, but I can't do it alone.

Comment: `[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]` is correct; just not in the same order as you wanted it. You could just do `result.sort(key=len)`. If you want them to be sets instead of lists, do `result = [set()]` and do `subset | {x}` in the comprehension.

Comment: and if you don't care about order, convert your result to a set. And compare sets, if you want to check for equality.